# Jquery - firefox bounce bug

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, cross-browser

My problem is, the following code works Chrome but not in FF. In FF the `<.txt>` element is going below the `<.cnt>` element, when `a` is bouncing.

It looks like float is ignored when element is bouncing.

How can I fix this?

**My html:**

```
<li class='tag_glass'>
     <a>
        <p class='cnt'>999+</p>
        <p class='txt'>some txt in here</p>
     </a>
</li>
```

**And my JS:**

```
$('li a').mouseenter(function(){

    $(this).effect( "bounce",{times:3,distance:10},1000 );

});
```

**And my CSS:**

```
li a{
  display:inline-block;
}

.txt{
    float:left;
 }
.cnt{
  font-size:9px;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: FYI: all <a> tags require href attribute, otherwise they will be an invalid tag. Use href="#" when you point to nothing.

Comment: ok thanks, but it doesn't help

Comment: I made a small [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV6JA/1/), and that looks like it works in FF. I don't see a problem? The list-decoration does jump around in chome though if the <ul> tag is ommitted.

Comment: Ok here it works, but that same example on my firefox, doesn't - i don't understand.

Comment: @Misiur: The `a` tag no longer requires the `href` attribute in the [HTML5 spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href)

Comment: Ok , check now http://jsfiddle.net/DV6JA/3/ - when i put smaller font- it jump up and down